# Procedural texture of random square clusters

Tags: texturing, procedural

I'm trying to procedurally texture some future tech. It has small squares that seem random. I envision making a noise texture pixelated, and then animating the pixilations to move over a cube object, looking very futuristic.

Ideally, I'd layer many pixelation colors over one another so the squares are like a kaleidoscope fading in and out.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to @Allen's answer.
If you also want the borders, just add a brick texture into the setup

[image]

[image]

Comment: AHHHH! I KNEW THE COMMUNITY WOULD COME THROUGH. thanks! this is perfect! if you want to see the alien stuff I'm doing check out my twitter. @andersonatlas

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project :).

Answer (score 5):

If you take a Voronoi Texture's *Randomness* parameter all the way to 0 it generates squares like you want.

[image]

You can take the *Color* output into a Noise Texture like you suspected and generate lots of different outputs.  What I did here was put a Color Ramp on the other side set to Constant to isolate groups of these squares to use as a mask for whatever you want.

[image]

But you can imagine animating some of these values and generating any number of visualizations.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Blender Material Haki]

The secret is in discrete of UV coordinates. Example on the picture.

Comment: oh this looks like a nice way to make digital camo :))